# Referral Credits not being recorded

Tags: branch.io

I have set up two referral credit rules.

1. All acting users get 7 default credits every time they trigger the event mq_app_open
2. Referred acting users get 10 default credits every time they trigger the event mq_app_open

mq_app_open is a custom event that I am recording on app open.

I can see that rule 1 is getting applied but can never get rule 2 to be applied.

What actually does "Referred acting users" actually mean?

I think the issue probably relates to the fact that when I open the app from a (universal) deeplink I see two events

- open
- mq_app_open

For each of Session Referring Branch Link ID, Session Referring Click ID and Session Referring Link URL are all null.

Oddly, when I let the app go into the background and then the foreground again I see the following events

- open
- referred session

For these two events Session Referring Branch Link ID, Session Referring Click ID have values but Session Referring Link URL is null.

I am not sure why any of these values are null when it would seem they should all reference back to the link url that was clicked on.

Answer (score 0):

Alex from Branch.io here:

**Referred acting users** is a rather confusing way to say 'users who take action and open the app after clicking on a Branch link'. We should probably adjust our terminology to make this a bit clearer. For most purposes, you can think of this as **Referred users**.

I am actually not certain why rule 1 is working but rule 2 is not. Possibly there is some conflict with having two rules applying to the same user from the same event — you could try refactoring the rules so that Referring users get 7 points and Referred users get 17.

Those session parameters *should* be coming back with values, assuming a link was clicked. We probably need to do a bit more debugging to see what's going on — would you mind submitting a ticket to the Branch [integrations team](https://support.branch.io/support/tickets/new) so that we can dig into the code and the backend config of your specific app?